# laravel 8, unique fields update using ignore() not working (and the method is POST instead of PUT) and getting error

Tags: php, laravel

Followed this [guide](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers) to simplify the CRUD controllers.

I used to have 2 forms, one for `create` and the other for `edit`. Now it's one form shared between the two. Below you'll see the condition of the form depending on the route:

```
@if($lostFound->exists)
  <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.update', $lostFound) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @method('put')
@else
  <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@endif
```

In the if statement I am telling the form to be `PUT` if the route is `update`. Even in the route:

```
Route::put('lost-and-found/edit/{lostFound}', 'update')->name('lost-and-found.update'); // Update record to DB
```

I tried ignoring the validation of the field by adding this line of code in the validation:

```
    public function rules()
        {
          return [
                'LFNumber"   => ['required', 'integer', Rule::unique('lost_and_found')->ignore($this->LFNumber)],
          ]
        }
```

I have a function in the request file:

```
public function persist()
    {
        // TODO: See if this can be refactored more.
        return LostFound::create( $this->validated() )
            ->addMedia($this->LFImage)
            ->toMediaCollection('lost-Items');

        $this->save();
    }
```

And I'm calling it in the `update()` function in the controller:

```
public function update(LostFoundRequest $request, LostFound $lostFound)
    {
        $request->persist($lostFound);
        return redirect(route('data-entry.lost-and-found.index'))->with('success', 'LF updated successfully.');
    }
```

Still when I try to update the data I get an error:

[image]

What seems to be the issue?

Note: If you're concerned about the Title, it was changed:

```
<div class="card-header">
        @if($lostFound->exists)
            <h3 class="card-title">Edit Lost Item</h3>
        @else
            <h3 class="card-title">Add New Lost Item</h3>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Comment: This is odd. Your form says "add new lost item" and you are hitting the update route with a pre-set id. Users can also change the ID in the form meaning you will potentially hit the update route for one id and pass a different id

Comment: @apokryfos True, it is passing a new ID instead of updating it

Comment: can you confirm the $lostFound exists ? 

```@if($lostFound->exists)
{{dd('Yeah we found it!')}}
  <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.update', $lostFound) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @method('put')
@else
  <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@endif```

Comment: @futureweb Yes, it's there https://snipboard.io/7lAVXh.jpg

Comment: Additional tip from the laravel docs about the ->ignore you are using: You should never pass any user controlled request input into the ignore method. Instead, you should only pass a system generated unique ID such as an auto-incrementing ID or UUID from an Eloquent model instance. Otherwise, your application will be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: The used method in the screenshot is still POST and not PUT